# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor does not run in sleep mode

Tags: android, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice, sleep-mode

Recently, I have been working on scheduling repeated tasks in background threads in Android application. I started with AlarmManager but due to its inaccurate triggers at specified intervals, I decided to use other JAVA and Android APIs.

I started with Timer and then ScheduledExecutorService and lastly ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

The problem with Timer is that it does not always run all the background tasks at right intervals. I had used it to run 3 background repeating tasks out of which only 2 were getting triggered. The third task was triggered after a couple of hours and to catch up with all the previous misses, it was triggered within 10ms (although the interval was 5 mins)

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is more accurate in triggering the repeated background tasks. But the problem with it is that it does not trigger the background tasks when the device is in sleep mode (screen off). The same is the behavior with Handler.postDelayed() which pauses the execution of tasks when the device is in sleep mode.

Now, I have reached a dead end. I am looking for a solution that could help me run my background tasks concurrently and without any interruption due to device going to sleep mode.

Please advice.

Comment: Which device/OS version(s) were you testing on?

Comment: I tested on Samsung S4 with Android 5.0.1